# Find the 9th element of the arithmetic progression given the sum of 3 times 3rd term, and 6 times 12th term

Tags: arithmetic-progressions

I'm trying to solve this sequence but I can't find anything related to my exact problem.

Given the following:

> $3$a<sub>3</sub> + $6$a<sub>12</sub> = 81

Specifically, I'm trying to find the 9th element [a<sub>9</sub>] <s>as well as `d` - common difference.</s>

I know of the formula

> a<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>1</sub>+(n-1)d

But not sure on how to implement it.

What would be a good way of approaching this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a_3 = a+2d$ and $a_{12} = a+ 11d $ , we get:

$$\begin{align}3a_3 + 6a_{12} &= 81 \\
3a +6d  +6a + 66d &= 81 \\
9a+72d &= 81 \\
a+8d &= 9 \\
\color{blue}{\boxed{a_9}} &= 9\end{align}$$

The question doesn't provide enough information to find a unique value of $a$ or $d$.

Comment: You're right, I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With $$a_3=a_1+2d$$ and $$a_{12}=a_1+11d$$ you will get
$$3(a_1+2d)+6(a_1+11d)=81$$